# Define multiple table variable with same structure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to define multiple table variables in a user defined function in SQL Server 2008 that will have same table structure. Without defining a user defined table type, is there a way to use the same table definition to declare multiple table variables?

Comment: No.  User-defined table-types are the way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I went your way.

Answer (score -2):

If you could use temporary table there is a way (not too smart I think, but it works):
create temp table (say ##templ) and then
`select top 0 * into ##templDuplicate from ##templ;`
will create another **empty** table with the same structure.

Comment: temporary tables are not allowed inside a function.